# Javascript Redirect URL with window position in div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a footer with some links:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('newServices')">
   Our Services
</a>
```

And if the user is in the home page the first IF works fine, but if the user isn't in the home page, this redirect to the home page, but doesn't open in the specific div.

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf('newhome') > -1 ) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},1000);
    }
    else {
        window.location = "/newhome/"
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},1000);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

*************UPDATE***********************

```
var userClickID = id;

    if ( window.location.href.indexOf('newhome') > -1 ) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+userClickID).offset().top},1000);
    }
    else {
        window.location = "/newhome/";
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+userClickID).offset().top},1000);
        });
    }
```

Still doesnt work.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the user to another page and than perform action on that page?

Comment: That cant work, cause "else case line 2" is never executed. You need to make the scroll animation right after the page was reloaded. Cheers.

Comment: @IgalS. Yes, i want the user to redirect and then go to the specific div

Comment: @lin any ideas how to make that?

Comment: I already told ya: "You need to make the scroll animation right after the page was reloaded. You can use "$(document).ready()" Cheers"

Comment: @lin i have added the following code: var userClickID = id;
  
  if ( window.location.href.indexOf('newhome') > -1 ) {
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+userClickID).offset().top},1000);
  }
  else {
   window.location = "/newhome/";
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+userClickID).offset().top},1000);
   });
  }
Still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm doing these experiments on local .html files in my desktop:
`file:///C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/page2.html`

This example uses the `?` url parameter to scroll to your div:

```
<a href="page2.html?newServices">page2 - newServices</a>
```

---

So create two .html pages in your desktop with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var href = window.location.href;
    var split = href.split("?");
    var afterSplit = "Error parsing url";
    if (split[1] != null) {
        afterSplit = split[1];
    }
    console.log(afterSplit);
    goToByScroll(afterSplit);
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.myDiv {width: 200px;height: 2000px;}
#one   {border: 3px solid green;}
#two   {border: 3px solid blue;}
#three {border: 3px solid red;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="one" class="myDiv">ONE<button onclick="goToByScroll('two');">goToByScroll</button><a href="page2.html?three">page2.html?three</a></div>
<div id="two" class="myDiv">TWO<button onclick="goToByScroll('three');">goToByScroll</button></div>
<div id="three" class="myDiv">THREE<button onclick="goToByScroll('one');">goToByScroll</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var timeMs = 1000;

function goToByScroll(ID){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+ID).offset().top}, timeMs);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tell me if this is what you want

Hope it helps

Comment: Shouldn't URL hashes be used for this instead?

Comment: @KendallFrey I've tried with the hash but it jumps quickly to the element #id in all websites by default with no smooth scroll.. I don't know how to prevent the default jump with hashes, do you know how to do it?